# Jquery get nearest element below selected and by selector

Tags: jquery

This seems to have been asked about a billion times but I couldn't find how to specifically do what I want to do, even though it is very simple:

```
<button></button>
<button></button>
<img />
```

Basically I want to click either button and have them update the image. With this code:

```
$(this).next('img').attr("src","newimage.png");
```

The lower button works but the upper button does not. It seems to logically be selecting the 'next' element, but however illogically not by selector since otherwise the top button would work as it would go on to find the next element that IS an img element.

I tried other stuff like closest() but that doesn't appear to do what it's name suggests it would either.

Comment: The `this` in the posted code has no context... please add the full code.

Comment: `nextAll('img').eq(0)` will get all the images following the buttons, and grabs the first one

Comment: It looks like the're siblings so do it like `$(this).siblings('img')...` .

Comment: @Taplar Yes that would work as well like in the answer below. I'm really quite surprised there is no function to get the next adjacent element by selector though. The basic next() should do this by default I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `next()` looks for the following sibling only. To fix this you could use `nextAll()` along with `:first` to retrieve the `img` you require:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('img:first').attr("src", 'https://i.imgur.com/CaTFJ0z.png');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>A</button>
<button>B</button><br />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/RGv7GmZ.png" />
```

Comment: That code does work. So there really is no genuine 'nearest' function though? It's weird you have to do this weird workaround just to get something like this to work.

Comment: This isn't really a workaround, it's just how it works. The DOM is a tree structure and 'nearest' is a very relative term. There's lots of traversal methods to go up, down and sideways, but there's nothing to explicitly say 'go sideways but ignore X nodes', which is why you need to do what I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes I just assumed next() could take a selector but I guess it can't, it just gets whatever is next with no option to specify.